# Showing the Fibonacci inequality $f_1^{f_1}f_2^{f_2}f_3^{f_3}\cdots f_n^{f_n}\leq f_1!f_2!f_3!\cdots f_n!\;e^{({f_{n+2}-n-1)}}$ without induction.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, fibonacci-numbers

Today I saw the following 2 beautiful inequalities on a facebook page.

> $$1^12^23^34^4\cdots n^n\leq 1!2!3!4!\cdots n!e^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$
>
> $$f_{1}^{f_{1}}f_{2}^{f_{2}}f_{3}^{f_{3}}\cdots f_{n}^{f_{n}}\leq f_{1}!f_{2}!f_{3}!\cdots f_{n}!e^{({f_{n+2}-n-1)}}$$

Here $f_{n}$ denotes the fibonacci numbers $f_{1}=f_{2}=1$ and $f_{n+2}=f_{n+1}+f_{n}$ for $n\in N$

Here is How I proved the first one.

**Method 1:-**

$$1^12^23^34^4...n^n\leq 1!2!3!4!...n!e^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

$$\implies\bigg(\frac{1^1}{1!}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{2^2}{2!}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{3^3}{3!}\bigg)...\bigg(\frac{n^n}{n!}\bigg)\leq e^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$$

$\implies \displaystyle\prod_{x=1}^{n} \frac{x^x}{x!}\leq 
e^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$

Now taking logarithm on both sides of inequality.

$\implies \displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^{n} \ln\bigg(\frac{x^x}{x!}\bigg)\leq 
{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$

$\implies \displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^{n} \ln\bigg(\frac{x^x}{x!}\bigg)\leq 
{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}-n$

$\implies \displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^{n} \ln\bigg(\frac{x^x}{x!}\bigg)\leq 
\bigg(\sum_{x=1}^{n} x \bigg)-n$

$\implies \displaystyle \ \sum_{x=1}^{n} x -\displaystyle\sum_{x=1}^{n} \ln\bigg(\frac{x^x}{x!}\bigg)\geq n$

$\implies \displaystyle \ \sum_{x=1}^{n} x + \ln\bigg(\frac{x!}{x^x}\bigg)\geq n$

$$\implies 1+1.30+1.49+1.63+1.74+1.82+1.90+1.97+2.02+...\geq n$$

$\implies 1+(1+0.30)+(1+0.49)+(1+0.63)+(1+0.74)+...\geq  {\smash[b]{1+\! \underbrace{1+1+\cdots1\,}_\text{$n$ times}}}$

This proves our first inequality.

**Method 2:-**

Using $\frac{n^n}{n!}\leq e^{n-1}$ for $n\in N$.

$\frac{1^1}{1!}\leq e^{0}$

$\frac{2^2}{2!}\leq e^{1}$

$\frac{3^3}{3!}\leq e^{2}$

$\vdots\\$

$\frac{n^n}{n!}\leq e^{n-1}$

Now multiply all above inequalities we get,

$\implies \displaystyle\prod_{x=1}^{n} \frac{x^x}{x!}\leq 
e^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$

Using the same approach for $2^{nd}$ inequality we get,

$$\sum_{x=1}^{n} \ln\bigg(\frac{{f_{x}}^{f_{x}}}{f_{x}!}\bigg)\leq f_{n+2}-n-1$$

Now I got stuck on this step.

> How can we prove the $2^{nd}$ inequality. Moreover can we show without numerically calculating(as I do above) that $\displaystyle \ \sum_{x=1}^{n} x + \ln\bigg(\frac{x!}{x^x}\bigg)\geq n$

Comment: You may wish to consider the inequality $n^n / n! \le e^n$

Comment: Some version of Stirling's approximation (or a rough estimate thereof) may be helpful here. In a very crude form, $(n/3)^n \leq n! \leq (n/2)^n$ for $n$ sufficiently large. This is possible to establish without too much difficulty with little more than the definition of $e$.  More precisely, $(n/e)^n \sqrt{2 \pi n} \approx n!$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: You're on the right path, all you need in addition is to show $\sum f_k =f_{n+2}-1$, say by induction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are known sums of the Fibonacci numbers
$$F_{n+2}-1 =\sum\limits_{k=1}^n F_n\tag1$$
and the Stirling's inequality
$$m!\ge\sqrt{2\pi m}\, m^m\,e^{-m},\quad m\in \mathbb N.\tag2$$
Then, taking in account $(2),$
\begin{align}
&1!\,e^{1-1} = 1 = 1^1,\\[4pt]
&2!\,e^{2-1} \ge \sqrt{4\pi}\, 2^2 e^{-2+2-1} \ge 2^2,\dots,\\[4pt]
&m!\,e^{m-1} \ge \sqrt{2\pi m}\, m^m e^{-m+m-1} \ge m^m,\dots,\\[4pt]
\end{align}
$$m!\,e^{m-1} \ge m^m,\quad m\in\mathbb N.\tag3$$

Finally,
$$e^{F_{n+2}-1-n}\prod\limits_{k=1}^n F_k! = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n F_k!e^{F_k-1}
\ge \prod\limits_{k=1}^n F_k^{F_k}.$$

The first inequality allows the same approach.

Answer (score 4):

The case $n=0$ reduces to $1\le e^{f_2-1}$, as its left-hand side is an empty product. Increasing $n$ from $k$ to $k+1$ multiplies the left- (right)-hand side by $f_{k+1}^{f_{k+1}}$ ($f_{k+1}!e^{f_{k+1}-1}$), so just prove $f_{k+1}^{f_{k+1}}\le f_{k+1}!e^{f_{k+1}-1}$. Indeed, you can prove by induction $m^m\le m!e^{m-1}$ for $m\ge1$. In particular,$$u_m:=\frac{m!e^{m-1}}{m^m}\implies u_1=1,\,\frac{u_{m+1}}{u_m}=\frac{e}{(1+1/m)^m}>1.$$